# Can you get an electric shock from a UPS output? If yes then can it be fatal?

Tags: current, power-electronics, ups, static-electricity

I have an UPS of 800 watts which means its output is about 800 watt.

I am installing a current leakage breaker to my main supply so that if I accidentally touch any things which produce current my breaker shut down the main supply.

I have also installed a UPS.

I want to know if the UPS power could be a fatal to any one.  If "yes," then should I also include it in my leakage breaker circuit?

Comment: I would not rely on a leakage breaker for protection. Keep one hand behind your back :-).

Comment: Yes and yes is the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, an 800 Watt UPS can potentially be lethal. It is very possible that the UPS outlets already contain current leakage protection (sometimes known as GFI, GFCI or RCD). So it may not be necessary for you to add it. Also, if you do want to add it, you could possibly do it using a GFCI extension cord or make up a separate outlet box with a GFCI so you don't have to take apart the UPS (and maybe void your warranty).

I know you may not be in North America, but I am sure similar products exist in other areas.

[image: gfci extension cord]

I found the [image](https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1196/6550/products/B00HRF2MP2.01-ARXGJPHMQP969.MAIN._SCRMZZZZZZZ_large.jpeg?v=1477943109) on leviton's website. Can't imagine they would object to me sharing it. The actual URL was from Shopify.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the UPS output could be fatal.

Comment: According to the interwebs, 100-200mA can be fatal. Thus at 240VAC this equates to 24-48W, so 800W should be more than enough to kill you.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it can be fatal.  It's a common misconception that the power (wattage) or current (amperage) rating tells you anything about its lethality to the human body.  In fact, *only* the voltage matters since the voltage is what pushes the current through you, and it takes only a tiny amount of current to stop a heart.  Almost all sources can deliver that tiny current *if* they have the voltage to do it.

Answer (score 0):

The UPS outputs mains voltage (120 or 220/230V depending on where you live) to power the devices that are protected by it. This can definitely be fatal and you should treat it with the same caution as you should treat mains voltage.